# Fallo en json_encode()

Tags: php, javascript, json

Buenas

Tengo un problema con una variable de JavaScript que estoy intentando inicializar con un json_encode() de PHP, pero después al inspeccionar el código de la página;
no hay nada dentro de la variable, es decir, como si no hubiera nada dentro de la variable de PHP, pero doy fe de que esa variable está inicializada y tiene datos... (de echo es un array) Aqui os dejo el código...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cesta']))
      {
$cesta = $_SESSION['cesta'];   // Aquí inicializo la variable de PHP que 
                               // viene cargada con los productos
      }

var cart = <?php echo json_encode($cesta); ?>; // variable que intento pasar 
                                               // a JavaSCript
```

cabe destacar que el JavaScript está embebido en un documento PHP.

¿Hay algo que esté haciendo mal?

Comment: no sera este el problema  `var cart = <?php echo json_encode($cesta); ?>;` ya que [echo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php) devuelve `void` tendria que ser asi  `var cart = json_encode($cesta);` y mejor si esta dentro del if

Comment: para mandar una variable de php a Javascript es obligatorio pasarla por un echo;  eso no es amigo

Comment: Tu codigo es incompleto y algo confuso la pasas de ese modo no tendrías que colocarle unas comillas para que JS lo tome como tal.

Comment: Tal y como lo muestras aquí, a no se que el valor de 'cesta' este vacio, funciona perfectamente. Utiliza el método `empty($_SESSION['cesta'])` y haz comprobaciones de que el valor tenga datos. Espero te sirva

Comment: La razón por la que puede no tener nada la variable es porque `$_SESSION['cesta']` no tiene contenido. Pueden existir otras causas, como por ejemplo, un error de sintaxis en alguna parte del código y `php.ini` no tenga activada la opción de mostrar errores.

Answer (score 0):

utiliza el isset para validar únicamente cuando el contenido sea valido ingrese, estas asignando fuera del if, por tanto puede llegar un valor vació... evalúa con json:

```
<?php>
if (isset($_SESSION['cesta']))
{
    $cesta = $_SESSION['cesta'];   // inicializacion var de session en var local
    $CestaFinal = json_encode($cesta);//operas la var. sesion con json_encode
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // viene cargada con los productos
  var cart = <?=$CestaFinal;?>; // varible asignada en js desde php
  console.info(cart);//alerta de consola para validar contenido
</script>

<?php          
}// cierre del if de isset
// continuar tu logica del sistema....
?>
```

Sobre la forma como asignas a cart podrías hacer primero la operación de json_encode y posteriormente la asignacion en javascript, de esta forma evitas que haga dos operaciones a la vez que puede afectar tu código.

Comment: Todo ese código estaba bien; ya lo he resuelto; el problema rádicaba en que un campo venía en binario y daba el error de carácteres invalidos muchas gracias por la atención